# groupby multiple columns and sum then sum in dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I am grouping dataframe by 3 columns (`v1, v2, v3`) with `dplyr` and the sum the 4th column (`v4`) in this grouping. However, my following code only gives the sum of `v4` (a single value) in all dataframe rather using the group.

```
 df %>%
    group_by(v1, v2, v3) %>%
    summarise(sumv4 = sum(v4))
```

df

```
 v1  v2  v3  v4
  1   0   5   1
  1   0   5   1
  1   0   5   0
  2   1   5   1
  2   1   5   0
  3   2   4   1
  3   2   4   0
```

expected output

```
  v1  v2  v3  v4
  1   0   5   2
  2   1   5   1
  3   2   4   1
```

Thanks!

Comment: I get expected output running on my machine

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(v1, v2, v3) %>% dplyr::summarise(sumv4 = sum(v4))`. It might be `plyr`'s `summarise` that you're using.

Comment: If you are having issues with different versions of functions, you might want to try the strict package `https://github.com/hadley/strict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I posted works, the issue turns out to be in my package version. It will be solved if specify the package name.

```
df %>%
group_by(v1, v2, v3) %>%
dplyr::summarise(sumv4 = sum(v4))
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Just one more note: the issue is a package conflict. Make sure you load `plyr` first, then `dplyr` (in case you need both packages). You should see a warning if you do it the other way around.

Comment: Good note, that is exactly what I did in the loading. Thanks! @markus